# javascript substring like backspace

Tags: javascript, html, substring, backspace

HI in the code down below i have a html setup with buttons for a password input form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Log in form</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="ui.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main">
         <div id="top_bar"><tx id="tx">Bildschirmsperre</tx></div>
         <div id="infotext">Wählen sie Ihre PIN aus</div><br />
         <div id="pin"></div><button id="btnback" onclick="changepin(10)">&larr;</button><br />

         <div id="tasten">
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(1)">1</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(2)">2</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(3)">3</button><br />
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(4)">4</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(5)">5</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(6)">6</button><br />
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(7)">7</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(8)">8</button>
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(9)">9</button><br />
            <button class="button" onclick="changepin(0)">0</button>
         </div>
         <div id="bottom_bar">   <text id="text_left">ABBRECHEN</text>  <zeichen id="zeichen">|</zeichen>   <text id="text_right">WEITER</text> </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

There is no css so it looks awful right now and it contains words in germany so please ignore them.

so far i have this javascript:

```
var count = 0;

function changepin(value) {
   var pin = document.getElementById("pin");
   if(value != 10 && count < 4){
      pin.innerHTML += value;
      count++;
   }else if(value == 10){
      count--;
      pin.innerHTML = pin.value.substr(0, count);
   }
}
```

the typing in (max 4 letters) works fine but i have no idea how to make the backspace  i tried a little bit but it isnt working.

Could anyone pls help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, but the use of the `count` variable is both unnecessary and potentially confusing.  This does what you need, without it...

```
// only do this once - no need to find the element every time
var pin = document.getElementById("pin");

function changepin(value) {
    var currentPin = pin.innerText;

    // if user pressed the back button then remove the last character
    if (value == 10) {
        pin.innerText = currentPin.substr(0, currentPin.length - 1);
    }
    // else if the current pin is long enough then just exit without doing anything else
    else if (currentPin.length > 3) {
        return;
    }
    // else add the new character to the pin
    else {
        pin.innerText = currentPin + value;
    }
}
```

As you can see I also changed `innerHTML` to `innerText`.  In this case it makes no difference, but it's good habit to always refer to the correct property, so you want to set the text, not the HTML.

Comment: What if `pin` only is 2 characters long and you still want to use backspace? Edit: That's what I'm talking about, here's your upvote!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get the value of `<div id="pin">`. A `div` has no value. Exchange the following line:

`pin.innerHTML = pin.value.substr(0, count);`

With this one:

`pin.innerHTML = pin.innerHTML.substr(0, count);`

Also, there are some things you should clean up. For example, only use valid html tags. `<text>` and `<zeichen>` are not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your js function like that

```js
function changepin(value) {
  var pin = document.getElementById("pin");
  if (value != 10 && count < 4) {
    pin.innerHTML += value;
    count++;
  } else if (value == 10) {
    count--;
    pin.innerHTML = pin.innerHTML.substring(0, pin.innerHTML.length - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what i was looking for!